# i try store user id in django admin panel like laravel

Tags: django

Im a beginner in Django framework 
I used Laravel before and in Laravel i can store user login info or user_id with this codes:

```
auth()->user()

auth()->user()->id
```

in Django framework is any similar code for taking user_id?

for example in laravel:

```
Article::create(['user_id'=>auth()->user()->id]);
```

what about django default adminpanel?(there is no views for using request.user.id ,only model.py and admin.py)

my model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user        =   models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name="user_article_category",editable=False)
```

Comment: "In my model"…? The `request` object is available in views/request handlers, not in models. Your models are independent from individual requests. Your views/request handlers should pass the necessary data into any model methods that need it.

Comment: thanks.i want to store logged user info like user_id in my database but i cant access that...i use default admin panel without views for handling requests...for example:when some author create the article ,automatically access author user_id in my model and save it

Comment: Edit your question to describe what exactly you're trying to accomplish, and maybe we can help you with that.

Comment: tnx for your help

Answer (score 0):

in you views you can access request user if the user is authenticated:

```py
article = ArticleModel()
article.user = request.user
ArticleModel.save()
```

or

```py
article.user_id = request.user.id
```